# How to get Ubuntu to recognise an AHCI SSD using RAID mode

Tags: dual-boot, ahci

I have a RAID0 on my computer with Windows 10 installed, so in the BIOS it's in Intel RST. I happen to have a Samsung SM951 AHCI SSD which I want to put in and install Ubuntu on. However, I cannot see this drive in Ubuntu (I already have Ubuntu on the computer in another hard drive and I'm trying to move it to this one) unless I switch to AHCI from RAID. However, when I'm in Windows 10 under RAID, I can see and format that AHCI drive.

How does windows 10 do it?

Can I get Ubuntu to recognise that AHCI drive under RAID mode?